# Does this series converge? $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \sqrt{n+\sqrt n} - \sqrt{n-\sqrt n} \right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

So I have following series:

$$\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\left(\sqrt{x+\sqrt x}-\sqrt{x-\sqrt x}\right)$$

and I have to find out if it converges.

By Ratio Test it gave me 1, so no answer. Wolfram Alpha told me that it doesn't converge.
Does someone has an idea?

Greatings

Comment: What is that $x$ while you are summing w.r.t. $n$?

Comment: Is $x$ supposed to be $n$? But in any case, a necessary condition for a series  to converge is that the $n^{th}$ term goes to zero as $n$ gets larger. Does it in this case?

Comment: Oh, well yes, x is supposed to be n. Sorry. It does not go to zero, so the series has to diverge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note:
$$\sqrt{n + \sqrt{n}} - \sqrt{n - \sqrt{n}} = \frac{2\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n + \sqrt{n}} + \sqrt{n - \sqrt{n}}}$$
$$=\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}} + \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}}$$
Which will tend to $1$ as $n\to\infty$

Comment: So when the Sequence of a Series tends to 1 or bigger, the Series definitely tends to infinity? Just to be sure :)

Comment: Your series will never converge unless the terms tend to $0$

Comment: @Dedechild if the terms tend to something bigger or smaller than 0, then you will be adding that number ad infinitum, that is why the series won't converge. Adding 0, however, won't change anything (to give the gist of it).

Answer (score 1):

Actually terms do not even tend to $0$. Since $x\mapsto\sqrt{x}$ is concave, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}-\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x}}&=\frac{2\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}+\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x}}}\\
&\geq\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}=1.
\end{aligned}
$$